# WPF Binding with RelativeSource and AncestorType

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application. It has a grid that is split into 4 rows. In the 2 row I have a datagrid that has its datacontext set to an object of OrderBlock. This all works fine. However I would like one of the column header text value of the datagrid be bound to a property in my view model.

Below is an example of what I have tried unsuccessfully.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
   AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ColumnHeadInfo}" 
   Binding="{Binding RejectReason}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Window` does not have a property called `ColumnHeadInfo`, but I assume your ViewModel is your Window's `DataContext`, and this probably has this property?!

If so, please try this instead:

```
Path=DataContext.ColumnHeadInfo
```

**EDIT:**
Since this alone did not solve your problem: The reason could be that the `DataGridColumn` is not part of the visual tree and thus cannot find any parent elements because it does not have any. Therefore, the `RelativeSource AncestorType` binding does not yield any result. This should be indicated by a warning in your output window. Probably, [this link](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) may help you.

Comment: Yes you are correct to assume that. I put DataContext.ColumnHeaderInfo but still not working. I have checked that my property in my view model, ColumnHeaderInfo does have a value too.

Comment: gehho is right, so pls check wether your datacontext of your window is right. use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Mmmh, the reason for your problem could be that the `DataGridColumn` is not part of the visual tree and thus cannot find any parent elements because it does not have any. Therefore, the `RelativeSource AncestorType` binding does not yield any result. This should be indicated by a warning in your output window. Probably, [this link](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) may help you.

Comment: _Made the above comment part of my answer..._

Comment: The link you provided in this answer was exactly what I have been looking for

Answer (score 2):

instead of controls i use "marker interfaces" to find the right datacontext.

"marker interfaces" just empty interfaces:

```
 public interface IDataContextColumnHeadInfoMarker{}
```

the view wich i know has the right datacontext is marked with the interface

```
public partial class MyViewWiththeDatagrid : UserControl, IDataContextMarkerLadeSolldatenCommand
```

and now i can use the interface with relativesource binding instead of controls or ancestorlevel, that makes thing easier for some cases :)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IDataContextColumnHeadInfoMarker}}, Path=DataContext.ColumnHeadInfo}"
```